# validate Msg in Record

Tags: scala, lift

When you call ‘validate’ on a MappedField instance, the field
FieldErrors generated by default use the uniqueFieldId method
implementation in the MappedField class, which gives an id of

```
<tablename> + "_" + <field name>.
```

So

```
<span class="lift:msg?id=<table name>_<field name>"></span>
```

I want to do the same but I am using mongo and record, but does not
work

Someone have any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

Fields in Record also have a uniqueFieldId, but since Record has many different persistence backends and is not necessarily table based the value is calculated differently.  In BaseField you'll find the method:

`override def uniqueFieldId: Box[String] = Full(name+"_id")`

Where name is your field identifier, i.e:

`val myString = new StringField(this,1024)`

name == myString